# How to get value from another table and count it

Tags: mysql, sql

This is like a voting system, lets says i have 2 mysql tables,

```
firsttable
Name     Gold
Rafael   1
Fabio    1
Rooney   1

secondtable
Club       Golds
Manutd     0
Madrid     0
Barcelona  0
```

what the sql query to update madrid golds with rafael's gold, so rafael's gold will be 0 and madrid's golds will be 1. And then if fabio and rooney give their gold to madrid also, madrid's gold will be 3. please help.

Comment: do you have table which links players to teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE
  secondtable s INNER JOIN firsttable f
  ON s.Club = 'Madrid' AND f.Name='Rafael'
SET
  s.Golds = s.Golds + f.Gold,
  f.Gold = 0;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e67c4/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to answer your first example; hopefully you can take it from here:

```
UPDATE secondtable, firsttable
SET secondtable.Golds = secondtable.Golds + firsttable.Gold, 
    firsttable.Gold   = 0 
WHERE firsttable.Name = 'Rafael' AND secondtable.Name = 'Madrid';
```